# File is not getting uploaded to the remote server

Tags: javascript, php, upload

I'm trying to upload files using this code. The files are getting uploaded in the folder called 'upload' in the local server. 
But when I'm trying to upload on a remote server the files are not getting uploaded. I can't seem to understand why?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['pgaction']=="upload")
    upload();
else
    uploadForm();

//The form having dynamic file uploader
function uploadForm() {
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title> :: FILEUPLOAD :: </title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="#C8C8C8" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<br>
<form name="frm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="pgaction">
    <?php if ($GLOBALS['msg']) { echo '<center><span class="err">'.$GLOBALS['msg'].'</span></center>'; }?>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EDEDED">    
        <tr class="tblSubHead">
            <td colspan="2">Upload any number of file</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txt">
            <td valign="top"><div id="dvFile"><input type="file" name="item_file[]"></div></td>
            <td valign="top"><a href="javascript:_add_more();" title="Add more"><img src="plus_icon.gif" border="0"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Upload File"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
    function _add_more() {
        var txt = "<br><input type=\"file\" name=\"item_file[]\">";
        document.getElementById("dvFile").innerHTML += txt;
    }
    function validate(f){
        var chkFlg = false;
        for(var i=0; i < f.length; i++) {
            if(f.elements[i].type=="file" && f.elements[i].value != "") {
                chkFlg = true;
            }
        }
        if(!chkFlg) {
            alert('Please browse/choose at least one file');
            return false;
        }
        f.pgaction.value='upload';
        return true;
    }
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}

//function to store uploaded file

function upload(){  
    if(count($_FILES["item_file"]['name'])>0) { //check if any file uploaded
        $GLOBALS['msg'] = ""; //initiate the global message
        for($j=0; $j < count($_FILES["item_file"]['name']); $j++) { //loop the uploaded file array
            $filen = $_FILES["item_file"]['name']["$j"]; //file name
            $path = 'uploads/'.$filen; //generate the destination path
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["item_file"]['tmp_name']["$j"],$path)) { //upload the file
                $GLOBALS['msg'] .= "File# ".($j+1)." ($filen) uploaded successfully<br>"; //Success message
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $GLOBALS['msg'] = "No files found to upload"; //Failed message  
    }
    uploadForm(); //display the main form
}
?>
```

Comment: check permissions on your upload folder on the remote server if you've developed on windows there's no local permissions issues if your remote server is a linux machine though then you'll have to set permissions to allow uploading to your folder.  if your ftp client you usually have to right click the folder and select "change permissions"

Comment: Files permission Is not a problem. I've given it all the permissions